# Vuetify v-dialog is mounted multiple times after use and is not within a loop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, modal-dialog, vuetify.js, vuex

I have two dialogs; SignIn & SignUp. The dialog use `:value="dialog"` instead of `v-model:dialog` since it the `dialog` is a computed data. The `dialog` is taken from a vuex module (popup). The dialogs are done without activator (provided by Vuetify).

If "Sign Up" button is clicked within the `PopupSignIn` component, it will close itself and open `PopupSignUp` by calling `togglePopupAccountSignInSignUp` and vice versa. **The Dialogs can toggle fine** but **ONCE** I fill in a form to sign in or sign up and executing the action. It signs me in and Vue gave an error (1st). Then another (2nd) error when logging out and opening the Sign In dialog again.

## Errors

### 1st Error

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined"

found in

---> <VDialog>
       <PopupSignIn> at src/components/popup/SignIn.vue
         <VApp>
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

### 2nd Error

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

## What I did

- Add :retain-focus="false" to both Dialogs. It removes the error but
  the Dialogs are still mounted multiple times
- Replace  `v-if="!this.user"` with  `v-show="!this.user"`; still mounting multiple times
- Use setTimeout before closing the Dialogs followed with router.push
- Reload the page every time a user logout. Although this *work*, I would need to always refresh
  everytime a Dialog is used

---

```
location.reload();
return false;
```

## App.vue

```
<!-- There is no loop going on within the header tag -->
<header>
...
<PopupSignIn v-if="!this.user" />
<PopupSignUp v-if="!this.user" />
...
</header>
```

## popup.js

```
export const namespaced = true;

export const state = {
  account: {
    signIn: false,
    signUp: false
  }
};

export const mutations = {
  SET_POPUP_ACCOUNT_SIGN_IN(state, bool) {
    state.account.signIn = bool;
  },
  SET_POPUP_ACCOUNT_SIGN_UP(state, bool) {
    state.account.signUp = bool;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  updatePopupAccountSignIn({ commit }, bool) {
    commit("SET_POPUP_ACCOUNT_SIGN_IN", bool);
  },
  updatePopupAccountSignUp({ commit }, bool) {
    commit("SET_POPUP_ACCOUNT_SIGN_UP", bool);
  },
  togglePopupAccountSignInSignUp({ commit, state }) {
    commit("SET_POPUP_ACCOUNT_SIGN_IN", !state.account.signIn);
    commit("SET_POPUP_ACCOUNT_SIGN_UP", !state.account.signIn);
  }
};
```

## SignIn.vue (PopupSignIn)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click.stop="updatePopupAccountSignIn(true)">
      <v-icon>
        mdi-account
      </v-icon>
      Sign In
    </v-btn>

    <v-dialog
      :value="dialog"
      :retain-focus="false"
      @click:outside="updatePopupAccountSignIn(false)"
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <div>Sign In</div>
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          <v-form
            ref="form"
            v-model="valid"
            lazy-validation
            @submit.prevent="login"
          >

          <!-- Rest of the form -->

            <v-btn
              type="submit"
              :loading="loading"
              :disabled="loading"
              >Sign In</v-btn
            >
          </v-form>

          <div>
            <p>Don't have an account?</p>
            <v-btn
              @click.stop="togglePopupAccountSignInSignUp"
              >Sign Up</v-btn
            >
          </div>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState("popup", {
      dialog: state => state.account.signIn
    })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("account", ["signIn"]),
    ...mapActions("popup", [
      "updatePopupAccountSignIn",
      "updatePopupAccountSignUp",
      "togglePopupAccountSignInSignUp"
    ]),
    async login() {
      try {
        this.loading = true;

        await this.signIn({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password.value
        });

        ...

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.updatePopupAccountSignIn(false);
          this.updatePopupAccountSignUp(false);

          this.$router.push("/your/profile");
        }, 2000);
      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The SignUp component is roughly the same with the SignIn component flow, the only difference is that it's for registering.

I'm not sure what's causing the Dialogs to be mounted multiple times. Any help to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a different approach to get the expected result using Vue `.sync` Modifier and removing the vuex method. More can be read from [Jithil Jishad's blog](https://medium.com/@jithilmt/vue-js-2-two-way-data-binding-in-parent-and-child-components-1cd271c501ba).

## App.vue

```
<template>
  <header>
  ...
  <PopupSignIn
    v-if="!user"
    :dialog.sync="dialog.signIn"
    :dialogSignUp.sync="dialog.signUp"
  />
  <PopupSignUp
    v-if="!user"
    :dialog.sync="dialog.signUp"
    :dialogSignIn.sync="dialog.signIn"
  />
  ...
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: {
        signIn: false,
        signUp: false
      }
    };
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

## SignIn.vue

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-model="dialog"
    @click:outside.stop="$emit('update:dialog', false)"
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <!-- FORM -->
        <p>Don't have an account?</p>
        <v-btn @click.stop="toggleDialog">Sign Up</v-btn>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    dialog: Boolean,
    dialogSignUp: Boolean
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$emit("update:dialog", false);
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDialog() {
      this.$emit("update:dialog", false);
      this.$emit("update:dialogSignUp", true);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```